# Minizinc: Issue in array assignment in if-then-else statement

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

```
var 1..5: k=1;
array[1..2] of var 1..48: key2;
constraint forall(i in 1..4,j in 1..48 where k= ceil(j/24))(if 
                 table[i,j]!=0 then key2[k]=j else true endif);
```

I am trying to apply this constraint in my minizinc program.Objective is to maximize cost function and this is one of the constraints but when i run this code it shows

```
Finished in 203msec
Compiling first.mzn with data empdata2.dzn
Running first.mzn
=====UNSATISFIABLE=====
Finished in 189msec
```

If I replace key2[k]=j with true then it compiles and run without any errors.
I am not using key2 array anywhere else in my program.I am using datafile to give input and i have initiailised key2 array as key2=[1,1].
I am beginner in minizinc and I am not understanding why is there problem in assigning number to array in this case?

Comment: It would help if you show the definition (and content) of table as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have initialised  table array as : array[1..4,1..48] of var 0..1: table . If I replace key2[k]=j with true, it will show output like this [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].My aim is to divide table array in group of 24 numbers and store the last index in each group for which table[i,j]=1.In this case expected key2 is [6,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the following model and it gave a lot of solutions (using "solve satisfy") for both Gecode and G12fd solvers. Which MiniZinc version do you use? I use the latest Git version MiniZinc 2.0 which is about the same as v2.0.2.

```
var 1..5: k=1;
array[1..2] of var 1..48: key2;
array[1..4,1..48] of var 0..1: table;

solve satisfy;

constraint forall(i in 1..4,j in 1..48 where k= ceil(j/24))(if 
              table[i,j]!=0 then key2[k]=j else true endif);

output [
    "key2:", show(key2), "\n",
    "table: ", show(table), "\n",
];
```

Do you have other constraints in the model not shown here?

Comment: I am using Minizinc 2.0.2 and G12MIP solver.The program ran successfully when i removed initial declaration k=1 (by declaring  k as var 1..5 : k).I didn't understand why this happened.